# Windows share folder mount error: cifs filesystem not supported by the system

Tags: ubuntu, mount, windows-subsystem-for-linux, cifs, sharing

I am trying to mount a windows share folder that is on the local network on the windows ubuntu terminal
The command is:

sudo mount -t cifs //xxx.xxx.x.xxx/foldername /mnt/x -o user=username

But I have:

mount error: cifs filesystem not supported by the system
mount error(19): No such device

What can I do to mount my ubuntu terminal to my local windows share folder ?

Comment: See this link and scroll down to answer by BW-userx.....https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/mount-error-cifs-filesystem-not-supported-by-the-system-4175593855/

Comment: This may help https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4423. OP did it with `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: Thanks for the links, is all working now.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I got it working with Microsoft's drvfs provider, as described in: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsl/2017/04/18/file-system-improvements-to-the-windows-subsystem-for-linux/

```
sudo mount -t drvfs '\\server\share' /mnt/share
```

Leave out the `-o` option with credentials, as it grabs those from Windows.

Comment: drvfs... not mentioned anywhere else.

Comment: finally something that works. everytime from mount -t smbfs through cifs didn't work

Comment: You saved my day. I successfully migrated my scripts using cifs by using this in WSL Ubuntu. By chance the remote server I access is with my Windows credentials.

Comment: Using rsync + drvfs on the linux versus versus robocopy + native file transfer was dramatically slower (drvfs) by a factor of 4.

Comment: This works in fstab too: //server/share  /mnt/share drvfs

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WSL 1, cifs may not be available. It is part of the kernel only under WSL 2. Source: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/613615/154924

See information on changing the default WSL version and on changing it for already installed distroes e.g. here: https://winaero.com/set-linux-distro-version-to-wsl-1-or-wsl-2-in-windows-10/

Answer (score -1):

your Ubuntu can not find cifs in filesystem. it is not necessary to add cifs.ko to kernel. you can dreat it in menuconfig in kernel und choose cifs in filesystem. after that copy the new zImage